# PSQL cte delete seem have have ambiguity when select same column from delete table

Tags: postgresql, delete, cte, syntax

Both these two sql can be execute , the first one delete all , the second one is logic right.

the first one

```
with d0 as (
    delete from seller_create_request
        where seller_id in
              (
                  select id
                  from seller
                  where email in
                        ('xx@xx.com')
              )
        returning seller_create_request.seller_id
)
delete from seller
where id in (select id from d0)
returning  seller.id;
```

the second one

```
with d0 as (
    delete from seller_create_request
        where seller_id in
              (
                  select id
                  from seller
                  where email in
                        ('xx@xx.com')
              )
        returning seller_create_request.seller_id
)
delete from seller
where id in (select d0.seller_id from d0)
returning  seller.id
;
```

The first one `select id from d0` it seem equal to `select id from seller`.
My original intention is `select seller_id from d0` but have spell wrong. It don't cause

`column id does not exist` since it from d0.

So I am strange why psql has this behavior, what I am missing from simple understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query will fail, because `d0` only has a column `seller_id`.

Your first query deletes all rows because the `id` in `select id from d0` cannot refer to a column from `d0`, so it is taken as a column from the outer query, and the whole thing effectively becomes

```
WITH d0 AS (...)
DELETE FROM seller
WHERE seller.id IN (SELECT seller.id FROM d0)
```

and that condition will be true whenever `d0` is not empty.

Comment: spell wrong for second sql. This seem like var scope in language. Can find in inner scope then the outer scope.